# При подключении слайдера не адаптируется текст

Tags: html, css, swiper

[image: вот что получается]

При подключении слайдера, в котором находятся карточки товаров (*изображение, текст, цена*), при адаптиве не адаптируется текст, будто у него выполнена функция `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: В таких ситуациях лучше не гадать, а исследовать код, пожалуйста, посмотрите и дополните вопрос.

Comment: И как вы назвали "функция" в CSS называется свойство, так на заметку :)

Comment: Вы попутали `white-space` и `word-break`. Слова по умолчанию не разрываются - нужно либо задать тексту `word-break: break-all`, либо самому вставлять в разметку т.н. "мягкий перенос" `&shy;`

Comment: также посмотри размеры блока. Может, у него где-то меняется display, при подключении слайдера